# Script Icon for Dock

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-dock

does anyone know or know of any script where I can make the desktop icons automatically add to the ubuntu dock?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a script, alhough one may be out there. However, you may easily create your own script if you know that

- Icons on the doc are registered in the dconf key /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
- dconf settings can be changed using the `gsettings` command.

For example, the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop']
```

will cause the tree mentioned applications to be permanently included as favorites in the doc. Your script would need to identify the `.desktop` launchers currently on your desktop, and then place these on the Dock, adding them or replacing the current ones, depending on what you need.

Note that the dock only contains `.desktop` launchers, i.e., launchers for applications or URI's, whereas your desktop can contain regular files and links in addition to launchers.